# Clearing select from drop down

Tags: jquery

I have encountered a problem with my code to clear a select:

```
$('select').children(':selected').removeProp('selected');
```

I bind a change handler like this:

```
$('#categories').on('change', function(event) {
   var category = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
   ...
});
```

This works except if I select again the option from where the selected property was removed `category = ''`.

I'm certainly do something wrong. Could someone please shed some light on it?

Comment: Are you getting the text of the selected option (as opposed to the value) for a specific reason?

Comment: @st3inn: .val() of a select returns a Array, so .val() === 'somevalue' returns always false, getting the text is just for keeping me out of this issue you can easily run into

Comment: no, it returns the value attribute of the option that is selected, consider: 
`<select id="Fruits">`
`<option value="Banana">Yellow</option>`
`<option value="Apple">Red</option>`
`</select>`
Here, `$("#Fruits").children("option:selected").text();` return either `Yellow` or `Red` whereas `$("#Fruits").val();` returns _either_ `Banana` _or_ `Apple` (not both, look at http://api.jquery.com/val/ and search the page for "singleValues")

Answer (score 4):

Completely removing the `selected` property may not be the best course of action. In your case, it looks like the DOM layer does not recreate it afterwards, so the `:selected` selector fails to locate the element.

Try setting the property to `false` instead:

```
$("select").children(":selected").prop("selected", false);
```

Comment: thanks, this does the trick and is the best option for my use case

Answer (score 3):

if you want to clear the selected value of a `<select>` drop down try:

```
$('select').val(-1);
```

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chgux/)

Comment: It won't work as expected if one of the `<option>` elements has its `value` attribute set to `-1`, though ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chgux/1/)).

Comment: or use any non-`<option>` value, `.val('meh')`

Answer (score 0):

Another way: this will always select the first option.

```
$('select').find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true)
```

Here's is a jsfiddle that compares @Frederic Hamidi's, mdmullinax and mine.

http://jsfiddle.net/RzEBg/